# Want to test Ubuntu Hard Drive from a Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, hard-drive, external-hdd

I'm just an intern trying to do my best job here, and the company I work with asked me to do the following: Send data from a Windows 7 PC to one using Ubuntu via an ethernet cable. So I learned about file sharing etc, and successfully managed to do so...

**BUT** it turns out they want to not just share files, they want me to have the Ubuntu computer listed as an external hard drive ON my Windows 7 computer.

Here's a mini checklist of what I need to more specifically do:

1. Treat an Ubuntu Desktop as an external hard drive to my Windows computer.
   (NOT just file sharing, a full blown external hard drive!)
2. Access the Ubuntu hard drive from my Windows computer, and run tests on it.
   (to be even more specific, I'm wanting to run a BurnIn Disk Test on the ubuntu desktop from my windows computer.)

So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:  start an SSH server running on the Ubuntu machine.

Once you do that you can mount it as a hard drive.

Take a look at Dokan SSHFS: http://dokan-dev.net/en/download/

Dokan SSHFS is a program that mounts remote file systems using SSH. You will need to install the MSVC 2005 redistributable: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=200B2FD9-AE1A-4A14-984D-389C36F85647

and the Dokan library available on the SSHFS download page.

Another solution is to use MindTerm: http://www.appgate.com/index/products/mindterm/

along with NetDrive: http://www.netdrive.net/ (both have free home versions):

Download and extract mindTerm

Run mindterm.jar (double click it if you can, otherwise in command prompt type in java -jar mindterm.jar)

Type in the host you want to ssh into followed by the username and password

In the menu click on Plugins>FTP To SFTP Bridge…

Type in 127.0.0.1 for the Listen address

Type in 21 for the Listen port

Select the Remote system type

Click Enable

Click Dismiss

Next we want to install NetDrive

Once netdrive is installed, open it up, and click New Site on the bottom

Type in localhost (or whatever you want to call it) for the Site name

Type in localhost for the Site IP

Type in 21 for the Port

Select FTP for the Port

Select a Drive letter

Check Connect as anonymous

Click Save

Click Connect

Click the X to close the window (will minimize to system tray)

There you have it! A SSH/SFTP connection as a drive in Windows.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'll try this out but it will take some time, I'm doing a tutorial on SSH. Also, I noticed this link didn't send me to an address 'http://www.appgate.com/index/products/mindterm/'. I'm guessing the download from cryptzome works nonetheless?

Comment: I assume it does...

Comment: Here are some problems I'm having along the way: 1. MindTerm "Error in changeKeys (invalid key in Transceivercontext.init)." It says I am connected to the server running etc, but this error pops up afterwards. Is it possible that I'm messing up the username and password here? (there is no option to select anything other than telnet terminal in plugins here)  2. Should net drive be installed onto my Windows or Linux? I installed it on windows, set the type to FTP, port 21, name localhost...But it also asks for a URL, User, Password, what to mount it as, and no mention of an IP.

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure.  I've never actually used these, but someone else here has.  Help, someone else?

Comment: The question specifically said no network filesystems, but that is exactly what sshfs is.

Comment: Yes that's what it is, but there is no way not to use a netfs, except to physically remove the hard drive from the Ubuntu machine and place it in an enclosure, in which case, it would be about as cheap to just buy a 2TB external HDD.